# How do I change the title and date of quantmod chart?

Tags: r, plot, title, quantmod

I am using quantmod like this;

```
library(quantmod)
d<- data.frame(Open = rep(2,10), High = rep(5,10), Low = rep(1,10),  Close = rep(4,10), Volume = rep(100,10))
head(d)
data<-as.xts(d, tzone = Sys.getenv("GMT"), order.by =as.POSIXct(as.character(seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2015/1/10"), "day"))))
chartSeries(data )
```

to generate a chart like this:

[image]

How do I change the text that appears above the chart. You can see the "data" and the date that I put in a red box. How Can I change the title and date?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about the date-range, but you can replace `data` using the `name` argument to `chartSeries`, like `chartSeries(data, name="new name")`.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to change the date range to something other than the actual date range?